# Is there some way for check if an html attribute is not part of DOM HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been trying to check if some attributes are not part of `DOM HTML5` attributes. The code traverses the `html` markup and save on a `Set`. My idea is to identify in this example the attributes `ng-controller`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-bind` because the other attributes (`id` and `class`) are part of `DOM HTML5` attributes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="html-markup">
        <div class="class-1" ng-controller="myController">
            <table id="the-table">
                <thead class="table-header" >
                        <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in myList[0] track by key">
                            {{ key }}
                        </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table-body">
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in myList track by item.id">
                        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
                            <span ng-bind="value"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
const element = document.getElementById("html-markup");
const allChildrensNodes = element.childNodes;
const allChildrensElements = element.getElementsByTagName("*");
const attributesArray = Array.from(allChildrensElements)
        .reduce((set, child) => {
            Array.from(child.attributes).forEach((attr) => {
                //if(ATTRIBUTE IS NOT PART OF DOM HTML5 ATTRIBUTES)
                set.add(attr.name)
            });
            return set;
        }, new Set())

console.log(attributesArray);//Set(5) {"class", "ng-controller", "id", "ng-repeat", "ng-bind"}
```

**Is there some hack or trick to check this?**

a `codepen` for play with this: https://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/veWKOj?editors=1010

Comment: can you precise what is the final goal for this? As it would be much easier to do the contrary and check for definite attributes (or prefixes like "ng-") instead of filtering out the "regular" ones. There are JSON lists on the web for regular ones, but i don't think that guarantees to be browser-variations proof..

Comment: Since HTML5 is a “living thing”, and doesn’t have versions any more, such a list would not be static to begin with, but change over time ...

Comment: @Kaddath my idea it is identify the non standard attributes for replace his value for a placeholder. the idea for this will be do snapshot testing (https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html). the problem for check "ng-" by example it's that exists another prefixes like "ui-" or "md-" or whatever you want if you create custom directives.

Comment: You can use a xpath query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi If you want to collect start with "ng-" you can add below code insted`

```
if(attr.name.startsWith('ng-'))
  set.add(attr.name)
```

Or you can make your own array with full attribute list in [in this link (HTML attribute reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

```
    const fullAttributeList = ['class','name','id',.....];
   ..
   ..
   ..
    if(fullAttributeList.indexOf(attr.name) ===-1)
      set.add(attr.name)
```

Comment: Thanks, i use your link from mdn and the list of attributes was enough for me. Simply use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".standard-table tbody tr td:nth-child(1)")).map((c) => c.innerText)` in the chrome console and get the list :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's any short-cut here. You'll have to build a list of the valid attributes per tag type (and note some are only valid when others have a particular value) based on [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1). While *many* attributes have reflected properties you could check for, A) Not all do, B) the names of the reflected properties are not always the same as the attributes they reflect; C) some properties have the same name as attributes but *aren't* directly reflected (though they're usually related in some way, even if loosely; `value` isn't a reflected property for the `value` attribute, for instance; the property is `defaultValue`).

Comment: That link is great -- you could grab the page via AJAX, build your list, then run through it for each element.

Comment: @freginold: Wow -- I was going to say "Probably not, cross-origin call" but the W3C supports CORS for that page! (Glad I checked...) Worked from jsfiddle and from localhost, so I figure they have it wide open.